Romantic comedy film about friends who fall in love with each other
Genres: Romantic, comedy
Story: 

Start: The movie starts with a plane scene where boy was afraid of flying but girl tries to cheer him up.
Middle: Both girl and boy are adults now and are good friends. Girl is cheerful but boy is kind of a serious person. The relationship is very tough for him, but for the girl things are comparatively easy. 
The specific scene I remember is when the girl forces the boy to go with her to a separate kind of night club, where in middle stage people dance on similar steps and the girl is aware of the steps but the boy learns them after some trouble. And suddenly water comes from the stage on the dancers and later foam too. Their cloths become messy, but both of them enjoy it. I think boy was a little stressed before this dance.
End: I think they both fall in love in mid-between but refuse to confess. I think they even had sex once. I didn't remember the exact ending but it most probably is a happy ending.

Release year: Looks like a late 90s film or may be early 2000s.

Sounds like Boys and Girls (2000) with Freddie Prinze Jr. and Claire Forlani. 
From the IMDB synopsis:

On a flight from New York to Los Angeles, the twelve-year-old Ryan Walker sits next to a girl named Jennifer. Four years later at Harding High School, Jennifer  is named homecoming queen while Ryan has an accident while in uniform as the team's mascot. When they talk afterwards, Jennifer realizes that he is the same guy from the flight and asks him out for coffee, but they argue and Ryan declines. Even later, Ryan is a freshman at Berkeley... It turns out Jennifer also goes to Berkeley....They spend a day together in San Francisco and go dancing at night...

Here is the trailer on youtube and it appears to have the night club scene with the foam.
